# In python detect regex pattern match to capture content before and after a specific sequence

Tags: python, regex

In python how do I create a regex that captures what is before and after this regex pattern `r(?!^no_|_no_)like_thi(?:s|)"`.

Being that `"like_thi(?:s|)"` must not be preceded by `"(?!^not_|_not_)"` .

`?!` is a "negative lookahead." It is used to perform a negative assertion of a pattern in the string.

The following regex pattern is not working for me:

```py
import re

test_string = "ohh_you_not_like_this_things_yet" #case 1
test_string = "not_like_this_things_yet" #case 2
test_string = "ohh_younot_like_this_things_yet" #case 3

a, b = "", ""

regex_pattern = r"(.*)(?!^not_|_not_)like_thi(?:s|)(.*)\s*=\s*"

match = re.search(regex_pattern, line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if match:
    print("detect pattern!!!\n"
    a = match.group(1).strip()
    b = match.group(2).strip()

#print results
print(a)
print(b)
```

For the capturing groups I have used `.*` is a pattern that represents any character (except newline) repeated zero or more times.

The expected result would be:

```
#case 1
""
""

#case 2
""
""

#case 3
detect pattern!!!

"ohh younot "
" things yet"
```

I modify to make my code work correctly?

Comment: You need a lookbehind, `(?<!_no_)(?<!^no_)like_this?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need a lookbehind that does not allow cases like "hdhdh not_like_this_thing" but does allow cases like "hdhdhnot_like_this_thing" and in this last case it would capture "hdhdhnot_" and "_thing". I use for that a multi condicional regex using (?! | )

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there something wrong with the formulation of the question?

Comment: Bertina, hello. Re-read the chapter on _`Assertions`_. There is a single current position in regex matching. The current position in a target string is where the current regex position tries to match. If there is a match, the current position advances by the amount of characters the regex matched from it's current position. The regex position advances if it can match starting at the the current target position.

Comment: Here is the code analogy. An Assertion is an _`if()`_ statement. It cannot advance the current position in the target. All it can do is examine the target at the current position. So it can look behind, or look ahead, etc.. If the conditional succeeds, the regex position advances to the next section. It is _CODE_ like any other. So if I were not allowing 'ABC' forward from the current position, I will always match 'XYZ' from that position making the assertion useless and unnecessary. That is precisely what you are doing

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/HjxIwx/2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![_\s]not_)(?<!^not_)like_this?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HjxIwx/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<![_\s]not_)` - immediately on the left, there should be no `_not_` or whitespace + `not_`
- `(?<!^not_)` - immediately on the left, there should be no `not_` at the start of the string
- `like_this?` - `like_thi` and an optional `s`